# Repay / reclaim duty / tax on items bought in Australia

Tags: australia, tax-refunds

I don't live in Australia but bought items while there and got GST back from TRS.

Now when I come back to Australia with those items, do I have to pay the GST back even if I won't leave those items there but take them with me when I leave?

And if so, can I reclaim that money when I leave Australia? As it is explained, GST can only be claimed within 60 days of purchase.

So does it mean that I permanently lose the GST refund just by carrying those items with me?

My question is related to the one below but that one doesn't answer my case.
[Duty on items bought in Australia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/133205/27461)

Answer (score 1):

If your goods are less than $900 (per person, if you're travelling in a family group) you're fine regardless as you don't need to declare them.

If your goods are over $900 and you're bringing them back into Australia, then yes, [you will need to declare them and pay GST](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/tourist-refund-scheme/for-travellers).

Practically, if you have lived overseas for a number of years it is unlikely (and some might argue unreasonable) for you to be pulled up with goods that may or may not have been bought in Australia, but if it is only a short stay overseas before you've returned to Australia it can be argued that it is breaching the TRS anyway - you're returning to Australia with goods refunded for overseas usage.

Obviously leaving the goods at your home overseas would mitigate any issues.